# Get message content from compose window in Outlook 2011

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript, osx-snow-leopard

I am using Applescript to get the content of a message in Compose Window in Outlook 2011.

By using System Events I can use Ctrl A and then Ctrl C to paste the contents in Clipboard and proceed.
Is there any other way to get the contents in the frontmost Compose Window using Applescript?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. **Command**-A and **Command**-C (remember that!) is the way to go.

Comment: I was a newbie to MAC at that time :) Thanks!